# Mac Mini Won't boot with a PC keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard

The Mini was installed with Windows 2003 now and its the only OS installed. It's a Mac Mini A1176 and now I want to install reformat the box and install Mac OSX.

But the problem is unlike any other Mac products I have, by holding 'c', 'shift', 'option', or 'd' on the keyboard immediately after power on the box cannot successfully change the booting sequence, it only boots from hard disk which is installed with Windows now.

I think the problem is that I'm not using a Mac keyboard, but a normal PC keyboard, is that because it doesn't recongnize the keyboard at the booting stage?

Please tell me what to do to force the box to boot from CD, because I don't have a Mac keyboard with me right now.

Answer (score 1):

(reposting my answer from your Stack Overflow question in case you don't check that one)

If you have Apple's Boot Camp utility installed in the Windows installation, you should be able to choose the startup volume from its' control panel. Insert your OS X install disc, choose that as your startup volume, and reboot.